# Set Context key in jquery without auto complete behaviour id

Tags: jquery, asp.net-3.5, user-controls

I am working on usercontrol contains textbox with autocomplete extender, adding this user control in my page it works great till when i started to set context key in jquery now i'm in problem to set contextkey because using this code 
 **$find('AutoCompleteExtenderBehaviorID').set_contextKey(strvalue);** 
i'm getting javascript error like 
 **Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Two components with the same id 'AutoCompleteExtenderBehaviorID' can't be added to the application.**  so i'm bit worried to how can i fix this issue any suggestion please help me.
i'm bit hurry can any one help me.

Answer (score 2):

hey i got answer for this issue,
here is the answer,
previously setting context key in jquery follow some step:
1) set attribute of auto complete extender **UseContextKey="true"**
2) next use  **$find('<%=AutoCompleteExtenderID.ClientID %>').set_contextKey(contextvalue);**

hope this will help you all. Thank You